Arduino ESP32-S3 MSC FW+Files
I want both, a Config file on the MSC and also FW Update via USB.
Right now I can choose on a Hold Button which should be done.
But it shows always two Drives instead of one.
One Drive is empty and the other one is with a file.
What do I need to change, that only one Drive is shown?
#if ARDUINO_USB_MODE
#warning This sketch should be used when USB is in OTG mode
void setup() {}
void loop() {}
#else
#include "USB.h"
#include "FirmwareMSC.h"
#include "USBMSC.h"
#include "FFat.h"
#include "FS.h"
#if !ARDUINO_USB_MSC_ON_BOOT
FirmwareMSC MSC_Update;
// USB Mass Storage Class (MSC) object
USBMSC msc;
#endif
#if ARDUINO_USB_CDC_ON_BOOT
#define HWSerial Serial0
#define USBSerial Serial
#else
#define HWSerial Serial
USBCDC USBSerial;
#endif
#endif

// Block size of flash memory (in bytes) (4KB)
#define BLOCK_SIZE 4096




// Flash memory object
EspClass _flash;

// Partition information object
const esp_partition_t* Partition;


void listDir(fs::FS& fs, const char* dirname, int numTabs = 0);


const esp_partition_t* partition() {
  // Return the first FAT partition found (should be the only one)
  return esp_partition_find_first(ESP_PARTITION_TYPE_DATA, ESP_PARTITION_SUBTYPE_DATA_FAT, NULL);
}


static int32_t onWrite(uint32_t lba, uint32_t offset, uint8_t* buffer, uint32_t bufsize) {
  //Serial.println("Write lba: " + String(lba) + " offset: " + String(offset) + " bufsize: " + String(bufsize));

  // Erase block before writing as to not leave any garbage
  _flash.partitionEraseRange(Partition, offset + (lba * BLOCK_SIZE), bufsize);

  // Write data to flash memory in blocks from buffer
  _flash.partitionWrite(Partition, offset + (lba * BLOCK_SIZE), (uint32_t*)buffer, bufsize);

  return bufsize;
}

static int32_t onRead(uint32_t lba, uint32_t offset, void* buffer, uint32_t bufsize) {
  //Serial.println("Read lba: " + String(lba) + " offset: " + String(offset) + " bufsize: " + String(bufsize));

  // Read data from flash memory in blocks and store in buffer
  _flash.partitionRead(Partition, offset + (lba * BLOCK_SIZE), (uint32_t*)buffer, bufsize);

  return bufsize;
}

static bool onStartStop(uint8_t power_condition, bool start, bool load_eject) {
  return true;
}

static void usbEventCallback(void* arg, esp_event_base_t event_base, int32_t event_id, void* event_data) {
  if (event_base == ARDUINO_USB_EVENTS) {
    arduino_usb_event_data_t * data = (arduino_usb_event_data_t*)event_data;
    switch (event_id) {
      case ARDUINO_USB_STARTED_EVENT:
        HWSerial.println("USB PLUGGED");
        break;
      case ARDUINO_USB_STOPPED_EVENT:
        HWSerial.println("USB UNPLUGGED");
        break;
      case ARDUINO_USB_SUSPEND_EVENT:
        HWSerial.printf("USB SUSPENDED: remote_wakeup_en: %u\n", data->suspend.remote_wakeup_en);
        break;
      case ARDUINO_USB_RESUME_EVENT:
        HWSerial.println("USB RESUMED");
        break;

      default:
        break;
    }
  } else if (event_base == ARDUINO_FIRMWARE_MSC_EVENTS) {
    arduino_firmware_msc_event_data_t * data = (arduino_firmware_msc_event_data_t*)event_data;
    switch (event_id) {
      case ARDUINO_FIRMWARE_MSC_START_EVENT:
        HWSerial.println("MSC Update Start");
        break;
      case ARDUINO_FIRMWARE_MSC_WRITE_EVENT:
        //HWSerial.printf("MSC Update Write %u bytes at offset %u\n", data->write.size, data->write.offset);
        HWSerial.print(".");
        break;
      case ARDUINO_FIRMWARE_MSC_END_EVENT:
        HWSerial.printf("\nMSC Update End: %u bytes\n", data->end.size);
        break;
      case ARDUINO_FIRMWARE_MSC_ERROR_EVENT:
        HWSerial.printf("MSC Update ERROR! Progress: %u bytes\n", data->error.size);
        break;
      case ARDUINO_FIRMWARE_MSC_POWER_EVENT:
        HWSerial.printf("MSC Update Power: power: %u, start: %u, eject: %u", data->power.power_condition, data->power.start, data->power.load_eject);
        break;

      default:
        break;
    }
  }
}


void setup() {
  HWSerial.begin(115200);
  HWSerial.setDebugOutput(true);

  Serial.begin(115200);

  Serial.println("Starting Serial");

  Serial.println("Initializing FFat");

  pinMode(0, INPUT);
  pinMode(17, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(17, LOW);
  delay(3000);

  // False for the msc mode and True for internal filesystem mode
  // Since both cannot write to the same table at the same time
  if (digitalRead(0)) {

    // begin(true) will format on fail
    if (!FFat.begin()) {
      Serial.println("Mount Failed, formatting...");

      // If mount fails, format the partition (Feels cleaner than FFat.begin(true))
      if (FFat.format(FFAT_WIPE_FULL)) {
        Serial.println("Format Success");
      } else {
        Serial.println("Format Failed");
      }
    } else {
      Serial.println("fat success");
    }

    Serial.println("Listing before");

    listDir(FFat, "/");

    if (!FFat.exists("/config.json")) {
      Serial.println("Creating file");
      // Create a file | use F("...") on file paths or it creates weird problems (idk why)
      File f = FFat.open(F("/config.json"), FILE_WRITE, true);

      // Write to file (using F("...") here just to be safe)
      f.println(F("{\n  \"r\": 255,\n  \"g\": 0,\n  \"b\": 0,\n  \"w\": 0,\n  \"offset\": 0\n}"));

      // Close and flush file (Not sure if flush is needed, but there to be safe)
      f.flush();
      f.close();

      Serial.println("Listing After");

      // Print directory contents
      listDir(FFat, "/");
    }
  } else {
    digitalWrite(17, HIGH);
    delay(3000);
    Serial.println("Initializing MSC");
    // Initialize USB metadata and callbacks for MSC (Mass Storage Class)
    if (digitalRead(0)) {
      Serial.println("Getting partition info");
      // Get partition information
      Partition = partition();
      msc.vendorID("ESP32");
      msc.productID("USB_MSC");
      msc.productRevision("1.0");
      msc.onRead(onRead);
      msc.onWrite(onWrite);
      msc.onStartStop(onStartStop);
      msc.mediaPresent(true);
      msc.begin(Partition->size / BLOCK_SIZE, BLOCK_SIZE);
      digitalWrite(17, HIGH);
    } else {
      MSC_Update.onEvent(usbEventCallback);
      MSC_Update.begin();
      digitalWrite(17, LOW);
    }

    USBSerial.begin();
    Serial.println("Initializing USB");

    USB.begin();

    Serial.println("Printing flash size");

    //Print flash size
    char buff[50];
    sprintf(buff, "Flash Size: %d", Partition->size);
    Serial.println(buff);
  }
}

void loop() {
  delay(5000);
}


void listDir(fs::FS& fs, const char* dirname, int numTabs) {
  File dir = fs.open(F(dirname));

  if (!dir) {
    Serial.print("Failed to open directory: ");
    Serial.println(dirname);
    return;
  }
  if (!dir.isDirectory()) {
    Serial.println("Not a directory");
    return;
  }

  while (true) {
    File file =  dir.openNextFile();
    if (!file) {
      // no more files
      break;
    }
    for (uint8_t i = 0; i < numTabs; i++) {
      Serial.print('\t');
    }
    Serial.print(file.name());
    if (file.isDirectory()) {
      Serial.println("/");
      // Ugly string concatenation to get the full path
      listDir(fs, ((std::string)"/" + (std::string)file.name()).c_str(), numTabs + 1);
    } else {
      // files have sizes, directories do not
      Serial.print("\t\t\tSize: ");
      Serial.println(file.size(), DEC);
    }
    file.close();
  }
}

